# php form - show email in from field

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I've created a PHP contact form, http://www.visualsgd.net/Testing/contact.php. I'd like to have the person's email completing the form show in the from block when form is submitted.
Here's my php:

```
<?php

// Set email variables
$email_to = 'cathy@visualsgd.net';
$email_subject = 'Contact Form';

// Set required fields
$required_fields = array('fullname','email','comment');

// set error messages
$error_messages = array(
    'fullname' => 'Please enter a Name to proceed.',
    'email' => 'Please enter a valid Email Address to continue.',
    'comment' => 'Please enter your Message to continue.'
);

// Set form status
$form_complete = FALSE;

// configure validation array
$validation = array();

// check form submittal
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // Sanitise POST array
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = remove_email_injection(trim($value));

    // Loop into required fields and make sure they match our needs
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {       
        // the field has been submitted?
        if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

        // check there is information in the field?
        if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

        // validate the email address supplied
        if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
    }

    // basic validation result
    if(count($validation) == 0) {
        // Prepare our content string
        $email_content = 'New Website Comment: ' . "\n\n";

        // simple email content
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'submit') $email_content .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\n";
        }

        // if validation passed ok then send the email
        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_content);

        // Update form switch
        $form_complete = TRUE;
    }
}

function validate_email_address($email = FALSE) {
    return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
   return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
}

?>
```

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: pass the html code as message in `mail()`

Comment: if you need live validation on email then you can use like http://livevalidation.com/examples#exampleEmail and if you are looking on Email MX DNS Record Check then you can use checkdnsrr http://in2.php.net/checkdnsrr

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the headers to your `mail()` like this..

```
$headers= "From: Senders Name <sender@someemail.net>\r\n"; //<--- Add the sender here (from)
$headers.= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\r\n";
$headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

Now, include the headers on your `mail()`

```
 mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_content, $headers); //<--- Add the above $header variable inside this
```

Comment: I'm now getting email that shows "sender@someemail.net" in from field. I want to show the senders email address. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Found the answer:  $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";

Comment: I am really sorry I didnt see your message.

Comment: No worries, Shankar. Just glad I've found the solution.